# Div classes appearing when variable is empty. How do I remove them?

Tags: php, variables, html, if-statement

I have an image gallery and below the image there is an info bar and a close button with the title and description of the project.

But the problem is, if I leave the title and description empty, the info bar and the cross still appear. I want them both to not be there when the title and description are empty. I can't put the infobar and infobar-close div classes after the if ($project1title !== '') etc 
 because then I'd have to repeat them for every project and then I'll have multiple infobar and infobar-close div classes.

How can I get around this issue?

```
<div class="infobar"><div class="infobar-close"></div>
if ($project1title !== '') if ($project1description !== '') {
echo '<span id="title"></span><span id="description"></span>';
if ($project2title !== '') if ($project2description !== '') {
echo '<span id="title"></span><span id="description"></span>'; 
if ($project3title !== '') if ($project3description !== '') {
echo '<span id="title"></span><span id="description"></span>';
if ($project4title !== '') if ($project4description !== '') {
echo '<span id="title"></span><span id="description"></span>';
</div>
```

Comment: You should use an array for your project titles and descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your logic around:

- first build the html string containing what you want to echo;
- set a flag on the way if content is found;
- echo your html string if your flag is set.

Apart from that ID's in html need to be unique.

An example:

```
$html = '<div class="infobar"><div class="infobar-close"></div>';
$content = false;

if ($project1title !== '' && $project1description !== '')
{
  $html .= '<span id="title"></span><span id="description"></span>';
  $content = true;
}
// etc.

$html .= '</div>';

if ($content)
{
  echo $html;
}
```

Comment: This works when I've only got one project like your example but when I start adding projects 2, 3, & 4 etc, it messes up. I'm guessing this is because I need a unique ID for each of them? How do I do I this?

Comment: @Emily Harris You should use arrays and then you can use the array index key as the number you enter after the ID as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask if any of the projectTitles is set and not empty

or you put all the titles and descriptions into an array and do a foreach ... this saves you some code

```
$infos = array(
1 => array('title' => 'abc', 'description' => 'blablabla'),
2 => array('title' => 'abc', 'description' => 'blablabla'),
....
);

if(is_array($infos) && count($infos) > 0){
    echo '<div class="infobar"><div class="infobar-close"></div>';
    foreach ($infos as $info)
        if(!empty($info['title']) && !empty($info['description']))
            echo '<span id="title"></span><span id="description"></span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an array structure for your projects. Something similar to the following:

```
$projects = array();
$projects[0] = array("title"=>"Firstproj", "description"=>"Lorem ipsum");
$projects[1] = array("title"=>"Secondproj", "description"=>"Lorem ipsum");
```

That way, you could simply iterate over the array:

```
foreach($projects as $index => $project){
    if ($project[$index]["title"] !== '' && $project[$index]["description"] !== '') {
        echo '<div class="infobar">
                  <div class="infobar-close"></div>
                  <span id="title">$project[$index]["title"]</span>
                  <span id="description">$project[$index]["description"]</span>
              </div>';
    }
}
```